# Extract data from linked xml using xsl transform

Tags: xml, xslt

here is XML file https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
i want to transform it using XSLT

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">

            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>

        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="sdk:license"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

can you please tell me how to extract data from that XML
Thanks

Comment: What data do you want extracted, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add namespace at the top of xslt and you get your desired result

```
<xsl:transform
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/addon/7"
        version="1.0">

        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">

                <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>

        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="sdk:license"/>

</xsl:transform>
```